# Multivariate quantile regression with splines in python

Tags: python, regression, spline, quantile

I wanted to use multivariate quantile regression with spline to analyze the data. The data contains three independent variables and one dependent variable. I divided the data into training set and validation set, and fitted the model on the training set and the validation set to verify the model. I used `quantreg()`from `statsmodels.formula.api` and the`bs()`  from the `patsy` to achieve this. But quickly an error occurred using `predict()`.

1.I don't know if this is the right way to implement my idea.

2.How to use `predict` in the above situation.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import patsy    
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(data.iloc[:,:3], 
data.total, test_size=0.1, random_state = 1)

train=train_x.join(train_y) 
vel = train['vel']
salmean = train['salmean']
em = train['em']
total = train['total']

model = smf.quantreg('total ~ bs(vel, df=3, degree=3) + bs(salmean, df=3, 
degree=3) + bs(em, df=3, degree=3) ', train).fit(0.9)

y_pre =model.predict(valid_x)
```

The information of the error:

```
PatsyError: predict requires that you use a DataFrame when predicting from a model that was created using the formula api.
The original error message returned by patsy is:
Error evaluating factor: NotImplementedError: some data points fall outside the outermost knots, and I'm not sure how to handle them. (Patches accepted!)
total ~ bs(vel, df=3, degree=3) + bs(salmean, df=3, degree=3) + bs(em, df=3, degree=3)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data, or some dummy data in the same format? It looks like the problem is with your train and test dataframes. Your train df appears to have columns 'vel', 'salmean' 'em' and 'total' in  as well as 'y', 'x1', 'x2' and 'x3', or it would error before you get to the `predict` line. If valid_x doesn't also have these columns, that could be the source of the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified the code according to your suggestion, but still got an error message: some data points fall outside the outermost knots. Does this mean that the scope of validation data set cannot exceed the training set scope when using spline regression?